# Access same index records from two different files UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have file1.txt as

```
data 1
data 2
data 3
data 4
```

and similarly i have another file2.txt as

```
record 1
record 2
record 3
record 4
```

In both the cases i have same number of records.

i can access each line from file1.txt by

```
for line in file1.txt
echo $line
```

I want to access the 1st records from both the files from single loop and so on.The reason i want first record from both the files in a single loop because i will generate html code based on both the data. If not in this way can anyone help the other way if possible.

Please Help.

Comment: What shell are you using where that for loop works? In zsh, bash, and tcsh it just echos the filename once and the loop ends.

Comment: i have edited my question. Please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paste` command  might help you, if what you want to do is join the files line by line.  It isn't part of bash, it's a tool that has been installed on almost every unix system since about 1979.  :-)

```
$ cat record
ONE
TWO
THREE
$ cat data
one
two
three
$ paste record data
ONE     one
TWO     two
THREE   three
```

Reading from multiple files at the same time is tricky in bash. Using multiple file handles is considered by some to be "advanced".

A bash script like this might be the way to go.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec 3< data

while read left; do
  read right <&3
  echo "$left /// $right"     # or whatever you need to do
done < record
```

This opens the file `data` on file handle 3 (leaving stdin, file handle 0, for the file `record`), and steps through each file, reading from both.

Alternately, if you want text processing in a different flavour, you could use `awk` (which is *not* bash, but usually installed anywhere that bash is installed):

```
awk '{getline B < "data"; print $0 "\t" B;}' record > combined.txt
```

This will walk through each file line by line, opening both files and reading a line from each.  It has the advantage of not taking a bunch of memory just to store your files.

Alternately, a higher performance solution would be to store one file in memory in an array, then process the other file line by line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next;} {print $0 "\t" a[FNR];}' record data
```

In either case, replace the `print` function with whatever processing you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
% cat data
data 1
data 2
data 3
% cat record 
record 1
record 2
record 3
% paste data record
data 1  record 1
data 2  record 2
data 3  record 3
%
```

Comment: i want to work inside a loop so that i can process the first data from both the files and so on.

Comment: So do that? `paste data record | while read a b c d; do echo $d $c $b $a; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
exec 3< file2
while read -r line1; do read -r line2 <&3; echo "$line1 $line2"; done < file1
```

Output:

```
data 1 record 1
data 2 record 2
data 3 record 3
data 4 record 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar advice that others have given you, but I'd read from each file in the condition of a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 data && IFS= read -r -u4 record; do
    echo "$data => $record"
done 3< file1.txt 4< file2.txt
```

outputs

```
data 1 => record 1
data 2 => record 2
data 3 => record 3
data 4 => record 4
```